# How can I pass headers using RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, http-headers, resttemplate

In my method I initially used `RestTemplate postForObject` method to post request to an endpoint. Now I have to add default `OAuth` token and  pass it as `Post` request. Is there any way I can pass both `request` as well as `Default Header` as part of POST request by using `postForObject`?

Initiall I used below `postForObject`

```
 String result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, String.class);
```

I am looking for something like below

```
             restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.POST,getEntity(),String.class );
```

Here is my code

```
    private final String url;
        private final MarkBuild header;

    public DataImpl(@Qualifier(OAuth) MarkBuild header,RestTemplate restTemplate) {
               this.restTemplate= restTemplate;
                this.header = header;
    }

    public void postJson(Set<String> results){
        try {
             Map<String, String> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
             requestBody.put("news", "data");
              JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(requestBody);

             HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonObject.toString(), null);

            String result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, String.class);
        } 
    }
```

Below is `getHttpEntity` which I want to pass with Post request

```
    private HttpEntity getHttpEntity(Set <String>results) {
          return new HttpEntity<>( null, getHttpHeaders() );
    }

    private HttpHeaders getHttpHeaders() {
        return header.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) For this sort of header, you should generally use an interceptor (which modifies every request). (2) You should take a look at the `OAuth2RestTemplate`, which already has this support set up for you, including token resolution from various sources.

Comment: sorry i did not get your question, you are passing headers in the above code right ?

Comment: Yes right, edited my code. I have to replace that with ```getHttpEntity```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can pass both request as well as Default Header as
>   part of POST request by using postForObject?

Yes, there is a way to do that, I can give a basic example:

```
HttpHeaders lHttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
lHttpHeaders.setContentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON );//or whatever it's in your case
String payload="<PAYLOAD HERE>"
try
{
    String lResponseJson = mRestTemplate.postForObject( url, new HttpEntity<Object>( payload, lHttpHeaders ), String.class);
    return lResponseJson;
}
catch( Exception lExcp )
{
    logger.error( lExcp.getMessage(), lExcp );
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work!!

Comment: please don't forget to upvote the answer as well, if answer is correct